# Removing column(s) from selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that selects a range based on the rows that have data in the sheet, starting with row 10:

```
Range("B10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

this works well, but by default it captures all columns with data. I'm not sure how to then change it to only capture specific columns.

for example, if I only wanted columns B:D for rows with data selected, changing it to

```
Range("B10:D10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

does not work, because the *SpecialCell*s selection overrides that and still returns all columns with data.

Is there an easy way to drop column(s) off of the currently selected range after *SpecialCells* captures the range?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `xlup` to get the last row filled, as in

```
debug.print range("B10:D" & cells(rows.count,"D").end(xlup).row).address
```

I'd also refrain from using `select` unless I want to return a selection to the end user.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using the selection for a copy+paste into a different workbook.  Does your solution still apply?

Comment: yes, it would. I'd use it as `range("B10:D" & cells(rows.count,"D").end(xlup).row).copy workbooks("My Workbook.xlsx").sheets(1).cells(1,1)`